# Cannot connect to Oracle database using jmeter JDBC Connection Configuration

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jmeter

Thread Group 
  Jdbc request
JDBC Connection Configuration

and i have added two listeners I am trying to connect to the data base without success getting the following error: 
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
)

can anyone help on this issue? 
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most probably didn't change the **Validation Query** in [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

[image]
Change :

> Select 1

to

> select 1 from DUAL